# Sorting in a custom order

Tags: c#, sorting

I need to sort some codes, but in a strange manner

I need to sort in a non-normal order, I need to sort the 40s first, then 50s, 90s, 70s, 80s, 60s, 20s, 30s, 10s, 00s.

What's the best way to go about this?

It's in C#.net 3.5

Comment: What is the rule behind that sorting ?

Comment: They are codes denoting types of product, and that's the order they want them sorted in this report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually provide a custom method to do the sorting (either to a sort method or a sorted collection class that holds these values.

Or are you asking what the algorithm inside that method should be?

For the algorithm, you can use the following methods:

```
int getFirstOrder(int v) {
  if (50 <= v && v <= 59) {
    return 1;
  } else if (90 <= v && v <= 99) {
    return 2;
  }
  // and so on
}

int Compare (int v1, int v2)
{
  int o1 = getFirstOrder(v1);
  int o2 = getFirstOrder(v2);

  if (o1 < o2 || (o1 == o2 && v1 < v2)) {
    return -1;
  } else if (o1 > o2 || (o1 == o2 && v1 > v2)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient way (especially for `getFirstOrder()`, but this should put you in the right direction

Comment: The algorithm, I'm looking for a simple way to sort in this odd order.

Answer (score 3):

Most sorting methods can take an `IComparer` object, so if you can write a method that takes two items and can say which comes first, you can sort using that comparer method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this

```
private class CodeComparer : IComparer<Code>
{
    public int Compare(Code x, Code y)
    {
        var order = "4597862310";

        var bodyStyleX = x.Substring(6, 2);
        var bodyStyleY = y.Substring(6, 2);

        // Same body style group
        if (bodyStyleX[0].Equals(bodyStyleY[0]))
            return string.Compare(bodyStyleX, bodyStyleY, true);

        var indexX = order.IndexOf(bodyStyleX[0]);
        var indexY = order.IndexOf(bodyStyleY[0]);

        return indexX < indexY ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```